# Is Jagermeister healthy for you?

Tags: health, drinking

I always heard that Jagermeister is very healthy for you and is a great digestive ,is all this true?Would a shot of Jagermeister make me more healthier or would the alcohol just be damaging me in time?

This is my first question on this site so sorry if I didn't formulated it quite well.

Comment: General medical onion is alcohol is not good.  Red wine has some good stuff but alcohol is not on the list.  Consult you Dr.

Comment: It sounds like good old-fashioned advertising to me.

Comment: @MickSharpe that is what I am wondering also.

Comment: Same for myself Chase!!! We were in a mold home and it almost destroyed us. Prayer and a little alcohol, but finding Jagermeister works very well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm no expert but I’ll give it a shot:

Jägermeister and other herbal liqueurs do contain herbal essences that probably have some effect on your body. But not in any medicinal quality, otherwise it couldn't be sold as food in the EU by law. There are strict rules (e.g. [Directive 2001/83/EC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_2001/83/EC)).

In general the usefulness of digestifs for the digestion is heavily discussed (there are opinions that the alcohol takes away any positive effect the herbs might have). But I don't have any reliable sources at hand.

And the alcohol is unhealthy, no doubt.

So from a medicinal point of view: stay away from digestifs and stop eating too much so you won't need any digestion-helper.

From a recreational or culinary point of view: If you enjoy the taste, a digestif is a great closure of a good meal and the psychological effect of "believing it helps" works sometimes.

And i personally like the taste and drink it recreationally and not just as digestif.

Comment: I also like it that is why I wondered if it is also healthy :)

Comment: Heh! I used to drink Amaro Montenegro when I worked in Italy. I loved the stuff. However, I can honestly say that it didn't help me with my Italian. It must be 30 years since I've downed a glass.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently alcohol is not unhealthy if you limit yourself to a drink a day.  Life expectancy increases with moderate alcohol consumption however if you go far beyond that life expectancy decreases.
I rarely have more than two  to three drinks a month however in light of this information I'm thinking of increasing my consumption.  
Whether the 50-plus Herbs in Jagermeister make it healthier or not I think it's a good place to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! That's a good answer but, next time let us know how you know something. We especially like links and references, you can see Silent-Bob up there included both. Keep answering questions and checking out the site, you'll fit in in no time at all.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having constant digestive issues for a few years now. Nausea whenever I eat, especially if the meal contains protein or fats.  I take ginger,  hydrochloric acid,  fennel,  and digestive enzymes at every meal to help,  but I still get nauseous constantly.... I also get constipated very easily.  My grandfather is from Germany, and recently told me to drink a small amount of Jagermeister with my meals to help with my digestion....now, I used to work as a Vitamin & supplement supervisor and learned quite a bit about herbal remedies,  so I have been aware of the benefits of licorice,  but I did not expect the results from the Jager to be significant.  I have been incredibly surprised at how well the Jagermeister has been helping! My stomach is emptying faster, as well as my bowels moving more frequently.  I am grateful and excited to be feeling so much better! Thank you grandpa,  for reminding me that Jager had been used in the old days as such a beneficial health tonic.  A little bit at the beginning of every meal has worked wonders for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Small amount of alcohol can reduce stress, cause relaxation, small improvement in circulatory system and provide psychological benefits. ıf it makes you feel good, tastes good, and causes no harm (if you do not over drink), then it is good for you. All these herbs ins,de may have some additional benefits although not medically proven yet.